# RuntimeError when calling `allocate_tensors()` on converted tflite model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-lite

I followed a [great tutorial](https://www.edeltech.ch/tensorflow/machine-learning/serverless/2020/07/11/how-to-deploy-a-tensorflow-lite-model-on-aws-lambda.html) on deploying a TensorFlow model using TF-Lite and everything works. However, when I try to use my own model (converted from saved `keras` model) I get the following error when calling the `allocate_tensors()` method:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-6b4d64de8090> in <module>
      1 #interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path='model.tflite')
      2 interpreter = tflite.Interpreter(model_path=lite_model_location)
----> 3 interpreter.allocate_tensors()

~/pyenv/srcnn/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tflite_runtime/interpreter.py in allocate_tensors(self)
    257   def allocate_tensors(self):
    258     self._ensure_safe()
--> 259     return self._interpreter.AllocateTensors()
    260 
    261   def _safe_to_run(self):

RuntimeError: external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/lite/core/subgraph.cc BytesRequired number of elements overflowed.
Node number 0 (CONV_2D) failed to prepare.
```

I believe it has to do with the way I've converted my model, but none of the options described in the `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter` are helping.

The `tflite` model I'm trying to load can be found [here](https://github.com/kingfischer16/srcnn-tf2/blob/feature/simple-api/srcnn-api/lite_models/20201107_basic_2x_srcnn.tflite), which is a converted version of the saved keras model found [here](https://github.com/kingfischer16/srcnn-tf2/tree/develop/trained_models/20201107_basic_2x_srcnn).

The [model from the tutorial](https://github.com/edeltech/tensorflow-lite-on-aws-lambda/blob/master/model.tflite) works without issue. I've noticed differences in the input details between the `tflite` versions of these models. For example, the tutorial model (working):

```
{'name': 'input',
 'index': 88, 
 'shape': array([  1, 224, 224,   3], dtype=int32),
 'shape_signature': array([  1, 224, 224,   3], dtype=int32),
 'dtype': <class 'numpy.uint8'>, 
 'quantization': (0.0078125, 128), 
 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([0.0078125], dtype=float32),
 'zero_points': array([128], dtype=int32),
 'quantized_dimension': 0},
 'sparsity_parameters': {}}
```

While the input details for my non-working `tflite` model are:

```
{'name': 'input_1',
 'index': 0,
 'shape': array([1, 1, 1, 3], dtype=int32),
 'shape_signature': array([-1, -1, -1,  3], dtype=int32),
 'dtype': <class 'numpy.float32'>,
 'quantization': (0.0, 0),
 'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
 'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
 'quantized_dimension': 0}, 
 'sparsity_parameters': {}}
```

Could it be something with the conversion? The model worked fine in development using `keras`, and should be able to accept inputs of variable x- and y-dimensions (image sizes). I don't think dtypes are the issues here since `uint8` and `float32` should both be supported according to the documentation.

Comment: As the error suggests,  `BytesRequired number of elements overflowed`, there could an issue with the dtypes `uint8` and `float32`. Also, the `shape` is different for both the models. This will raise an exception while running the TFLite model.

Comment: I'm also leaning towards the shape. However, the model should be able to accept input of any size 3-channel image, hence the [-1, -1, -1, 3] in the signature. Must the `'shape'` and `'shape_signature'` match? Can I change them in the model before allocating, or should this be fixed on model conversion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, pretty easy fix it turns out. When using a CNN with unknown input dimensions (i.e. `-1` in the `shape_signature` here, caused by setting `-1` in the input layer) the unknown dimensions in the input tensor are set to `1`. To get the model to allocate properly when using a model like this, you have to do 2 things:

1. Manually set the shape of the input tensor to be the shape of the input data, e.g. `interpreter.resize_tensor_input(0, [1, input_shape[0], input_shape[1], 3], strict=True)`.
2. Manually set the `dtype` of the input data to match that of the model's input layer, seen in the `'dtype'` entry in the input details.

It seems this is done automatically in regular TensorFlow, but the model must be prepared like this in the Lite version.

Edit: Regarding setting the `dtype` of the input data, this is done in the casting to `numpy.array` after it is imported from an image format, before calling `allocate_tensors()`. You can see the difference between the [TF implementation (line 332)](https://github.com/kingfischer16/srcnn-tf2/blob/feature/simple-api/srcnn_tf2/model/srcnn_model.py) and the [TFLite implmentation (line 77)](https://github.com/kingfischer16/srcnn-tf2/blob/feature/simple-api/srcnn-api/handler.py).

Comment: @NoSleep I have updated my answer for clarity.